# On permutation of elements of two bases of a vector space (Greub´s book)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let {a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>} and {b<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>2</sub>,...,b<sub>n</sub>} be two bases for a vector space E. Fix p, 1 ≤ p ≤n.  Is there a permutation σ such that
{a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>p</sub>,b<sub>σ(p+1)</sub>,...,b<sub>σ(n)</sub>} and {b<sub>σ(1)</sub>,b<sub>σ(2)</sub>,...,,b<sub>σ(p)</sub>,a<sub>p+1</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>} are both bases of E?

This question is the last exercise of the first chapter in the book Linear Algebra by Greub. I can prove the case p=n-1.

Comment: COuld you explain why such a fact is interesting/useful?

Comment: No. I´ve no idea why anyone would care about it. It´s just an exercise in a book of linear algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's also Theorem 7.2 in [Prasolov's Problems in Linear Algebra](http://www2.math.su.se/~mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf), which gives a proof and attributes it to Green 1973.